# Как поместить в переменную арифметическую операцию?

Tags: javascript

1. Как мне проверить ввел ли пользователь +, -, /, * ?
2. И как мне потом посчитать результат с знаком который ввел пользователь?

---

```
let firstNum = prompt('Первое число?',);

while (firstNum === null || firstNum === '' || firstNum.replace (/\d/g, '').length){
firstNum = prompt('введите первое число');
}

let secondNum = prompt('Какое второе число?');

while (secondNum === null || secondNum === '' || secondNum.replace (/\d/g, '').length){
secondNum = prompt('Введите пожалуйста второе число');
}

let arithmeticOperation = prompt('Какой знак вы выберите?')

while (arithmeticOperation === null || arithmeticOperation === '' || arithmeticOperation.replace ('как мне проверить что тут будут знаки +, -, /, *', '').length){
arithmeticOperation = prompt('Введите пожалуйста +, -, /, *');
}

const firstNumB = Number(firstNum);
const secondNumB = Number(secondNum);

const result = firstNum + arithmeticOperation +secondNum;

alert(`${firstNumB} ${arithmeticOperation} ${secondNumB} = ${result}`);
```

Comment: я бы чисто из злого умысла предложил вам использовать [eval](https://learn.javascript.ru/eval) по строке выражения xD, а если серьезно - ```if then else``` \ ```switch case``` \ .... :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы получить `Number`из `prompt` нужно использовать функцию `parseInt()` или просто `+prompt`. А чтобы проверить какой знак ввел пользователь нужно использовать `if` или `switch / case`

```js
let firstNum = +prompt('Первое число?');
let secondNum = +prompt('Какое второе число?');

let arithmeticOperation = prompt('Какой знак вы выберите?')

let result

switch (arithmeticOperation) {
    case "+":
        result = firstNum + secondNum
        break;
    case "-":
        result = firstNum - secondNum
        break;
    case "*":
        result = firstNum * secondNum
        break;
    case "/":
        result = firstNum / secondNum
        break;
}

alert(result)
```

```js
let firstNum = +prompt('Первое число?');
let secondNum = +prompt('Какое второе число?');

let arithmeticOperation = prompt('Какой знак вы выберите?')

let result

if(arithmeticOperation == '+'){
    result = firstNum + secondNum
}else if(arithmeticOperation == '-'){
    result = firstNum - secondNum
}else if(arithmeticOperation == '*'){
    result = firstNum * secondNum
}else if(arithmeticOperation == '/'){
    result = firstNum / secondNum
}


alert(result)
```

Comment: `как мне проверить что тут будут знаки +, -, /, *`

Comment: Не подскажете еще как проверить эти знаки +, -, /, * ? Если пользователь ввел цифры или буквы выдавал Алерт с просьбой ввести знаки